# onClick listener for touch screens and tablets

Tags: jquery, mobile, touch

I have a bunch of click listeners in my jquery and was wondering what I need to do to get them to work on mobile devices and touch screens?  So if my code is...

```
$(el).bind('click', function () {
    //my event function
});
```

do I need to do like...

```
$(el).bind('click, touch', function () {
    //my event function
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click` is perfectly handled on touch devices as a `tap`, so you don't need to do anything.

The touch device specific events are `swipe` and such.

Comment: no it's not. It hangs and has nothing to do with tap. I implemented tap separately and jqm click is not even close to what I got in result :)

Comment: Most of the time just using click has worked perfectly fine for me, but recently I've been having problems with it not firing.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery mobile. It has events exactly for touchscreens and tablets: `tap, taphold` etc

Answer (score 0):

If you get click events on regular devices you also get click events on mobile devices when "clicking" them on the touch screen.

You only need special events if you want to support advanced touchscreen/multitouch-related features.